# Is Double escaping a String wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, string, escaping

I have a database class that automatically escape input strings before building the query with mysqli_real_escape_string().
But it might be that in the script, a string is escaped and then passed to database class that escape it again. Could that be wrong? What could happen?

Comment: To answer the question you asked 5 times in comments... Imagine if you have a form input "O'Brien". Now if this is escaped twice, then you'll have the SQL query "... VALUES('O\\\'Brien') ...". This causes "O\'Brien" to be stored in your database column. If you then retrieve this and don't unescape, you'll display O\'Brien to the user, despite the value they wanted being O'Brien.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the first pass through [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), the following characters are escaped by inserting a `\` before each of the dangerous characters:

NUL (ASCII 0), \n, \r, \, ', ", and Control-Z:

```
NUL (chr(0)) becomes "\0" (chr(92).chr(48))
\n (chr(13)) becomes "\n" (chr(92).chr(110))
\r (chr(10)) becomes "\r" (chr(92).chr(114))
\ (chr(92)) becomes "\\" (chr(92).chr(92))
' (chr(39)) becomes "\'" (chr(92).chr(39))
" (chr(34)) becomes "\"" (chr(92).chr(34))
Control-Z (chr(26)) becomes "\Z" (chr(92).chr(90))
```

On the second pass through `mysqli_real_escape_string`, the `\` is escaped again:

```
"\0" (chr(92).chr(48)) becomes "\\0" (chr(92).chr(92).chr(48))
"\n" (chr(92).chr(110)) becomes "\\n" (chr(92).chr(92).chr(110))
"\r" (chr(92).chr(114)) becomes "\\r" (chr(92).chr(92).chr(114))
"\\" (chr(92).chr(92)) becomes "\\\\" (chr(92).chr(92).chr(92).chr(92))
"\'" (chr(92).chr(39)) becomes "\\'" (chr(92).chr(92).chr(39))
"\"" (chr(92).chr(34)) becomes "\\"" (chr(92).chr(92).chr(34))
"\Z" (chr(92).chr(90)) becomes "\\Z" (chr(92).chr(92).chr(90))
```

Double-escaping your strings does not create any kind of vulnerability, but it will insert many extra "\" characters into the strings you are saving to in the database.

The best way to do escaping is to:
1) Turn off magic quotes
2) Use queries with named parameters only, and do not escape anything before passing it into the query.  MySQL (and all other database vendors for that matter) will properly escape the strings.  (However, you may run into an issue with chr(0) terminating a string).

If you absolutely have to use string queries, escape the data once, and only once, just before it is inserted into the query.  Do not escape the entire query.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "dangerous character". There are characters that have a special meaning in SQL. And you have to escape them to specify their literal meaning instead.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have no good way of telling on the *other* end (when you're pulling data out of the database) how many times it has been escaped, inconsistently double-escaping a string will wind up with you having things escaped in your end data that weren't before - because you'll add two layers of escaping but only unescape one.

Basically, you need to have a constant *level* of escaping - either always escape things once (and unescape them once) or always escape them twice (and unescape them twice) and so on - but never mixed.

Comment: how do one unescape ? lets say if it gets escaped twice ?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with double-escaping a string as long as you have a guarantee of double-unescaping it before usage.

If you forget to double-unescape it, then the user will end up reading an escaped string, which is not very nice.

Comment: How can I unescape it? And why should I do it?

Comment: If you escape once with mysqli_real_escape_string(), then MySQL library will unescape it for you and you don't have anything to worry about, but if you have some additional escaping done by your scripts, then it will be your scripts responsibility to unescape it. As far as I can tell there is no standard MySQL library function for unescaping, so this can be tricky to do correctly. stripslashes() could be useful, but there is no telling what it can break.

Comment: +1 for mentioning double escaped. @Charlie Pigarelli: you may note that if you double escape **quoted string** on our query you'll end up get something like: `(SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE yyy = 'zzz zzz')` become `(SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE yyy = \'zzz zzz\')` <= the escape char **escaped** and become additional `\\`

Answer (score 1):

A doubly-escaped string will render incorrectly unless you account for this. You've probably seen examples of text occasionally rendering in an escaped form (with extra backslashes or HTML entities, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be wrong, because you can have things like **let\'s go** in your database.

You are escaping to avoid **SQL Injection** or query syntax error, not to "transform" the data you want to store. If you want to store **let's go** in the database, you should escape it only one time when building the query. You should not have to "unescape" a value that come from database. When you look into your database you should never see a value with escape characters.

Escaping is a real problem for beginners in PHP, that's perhaps due to magic_quote() function. You should take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php You should not use that feature, it's confusing. In your script, if you can't modify the php.ini to disable this feature you can do it at runtime with :

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
    foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
        unset($process[$key][$k]);
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
            $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
        } else {
            $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
        }
    }
}
unset($process);
}
```

Note this code come from http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Take your time to understand correctly how you handle escaping, you will save a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL use prepared statements and you won't need to bother with escaping the string at the database level.

And for PHP remember that you can use both " and ' to build strings. This you can use to avoid having to quote strings. If you strings starts with " then you don't have to quote your '.